# How can I communicate with a POS terminal from a web application?

Tags: javascript, web, tcp, cloud, point-of-sale

I would like to use a POS terminal with an web application. I can communicate with the POS terminal using JavaScript via TCP on the local network. However I need to communicate with the terminal from a web server. Is this possible?

Comment: I'd say you'd have to set up port forwarding and ask your ISP to allocate to your local network's internet connection a static IP - but a little more info is needed here. What POS system is this, and how exactly do you mean you communicate with it using JavaScript via TCP?

Comment: The POS is an Ingenico iCT250. It is connected to an ethernet port, and I connect to it as a TCP socket and write messages on this socket, all through JavaScript.

Comment: Yes you would have to use port forwarding and set it up for those specific ports. Ideally you would need to get your ISP to allocate a static IP - or you'll have to constantly adjust remote device to constantly use the currently-allocated dynamic IP - which can be very impractical. You can aso use a DNS, such as DynDNS instead of getting a static IP. I'm not too familiar with this though - I find the DNS route to be a bit...privacy-questionable.

Comment: I know old thread here... But @wrahim do you mind give some example code of how you connected to the iCT250. Thanks!

Comment: @galengodis sure, here is a small testing prototype for communicating with the iCT250: https://github.com/wahidrahim/pos-test. It makes a purchase for a specified amount. I wrote this years ago; apologies for the lack of documentation. Most of this is based on the documentation provided with the iCT250, for example on how to format the requests for the iCT250.

Comment: @wrahim thank you! I did try to find the official documentation, but haven't found anything to go from. So this is really valuable! Thank you again :)

Comment: @galengodis No problem! See if you can ask whomever provided the POS for the documentation/manual, it has some key information such a formatting requests, connection types, etc.

Comment: @wrahim I did, but they just wanted to sell me their own solutions :( So haven't found any manual yet...